# Mysql_num_rows not returning any value

Tags: php, mysql

What is the problem in my code ? every time it echo This image used as cover image , but delete query work properly.how can i fix it?

```
    <?php
     session_start();
     if(!empty($_SESSION['userId']) && !empty($_SESSION['name'])){
     include ('connect.php');
     dbConnect();
    if (isset($_GET['ximgid'])) {

  $del=mysql_query("Delete FROM project_image WHERE ximgid='".$_GET['ximgid']."' And coverflag !='1'");
  $delete=mysql_num_rows($del);
  if($delete==1){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sucessfully Delete !!!')</script>";
    echo "<script>javascript:window.location = 'projectImage.php'</script>";
  }else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('This Image Used As Cover Image')</script>";
    echo "<script >window.location.href = 'projectImage.php'</script>";
  }
}else{
  echo "<script>javascript:window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Consider using prepared statements to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What does the data look like in your database? are you sure the 'ximgid' you're using matches with one of the rows?

Comment: For delete query, use mysql_affected_rows() instead of mysql_num_rows()

Comment: try `if($delete!=0)` instead of `if($delete==1)`

Comment: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Your code is very procedural, consider OOP which is the better and IMO easier and cleaner.  It will help you tremendously with other OOP languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to solve my problem in an alternative way which is given below:

```
      <?php
       session_start();
       if(!empty($_SESSION['userId']) && !empty($_SESSION['name'])){
        include ('connect.php');
        dbConnect();

         if(isset($_GET['ximgid'])){
         $selQuery = "SELECT coverflag FROM project_image WHERE ximgid ='".trim($_GET['ximgid'])."' AND  zid = '1000' AND xpid = '".trim($_GET['pid'])."'";
         $flagtResult=mysql_query($selQuery);
         $flagRow=mysql_fetch_array($flagtResult);
         mysql_free_result($flagRow);
         $cover=$flagRow[0];
         if($cover == 1){
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Used as cover picture')</script>";
         echo "<script>javascript:window.location = 'projectImage.php'</script>";
        }else{
        $sql = "DELETE FROM project_image WHERE ximgid = '".trim($_GET['ximgid'])."' AND coverflag != '1' AND zid = '1000' AND xpid = '".trim($_GET['pid'])."'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        if($result > 0){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sucessfully Detele !!!')</script>";
            echo "<script>javascript:window.location = 'projectImage.php'</script>";
        }
      }


    }
 }else{
    echo "<script>javascript:window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
  }
?>
```

Now I can get my proper output.. Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_num_rows`only works with `select`statement.

For delete statements you have to use `mysql_affected_rows`

Here the part of the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) of `mysql_affected_rows`:

> Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only
>   valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result
>   set. To retrieve the number of rows affected by a INSERT, UPDATE,
>   REPLACE or DELETE query, use mysql_affected_rows().

Comment: @Khandaker Are you sure that records are deleted?

Comment: @Khandaker if you echoing `$delete` what is the value of that?

Comment: Nothing after echoing $delete , only blank page . @ Jens

Answer (score 0):

mysql_affected_rows() is the way to go

```
$delete=mysql_affected_rows($del);
if($delete>0){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sucessfully Delete !!!')    </script>";
echo "<script>javascript:window.location = 'projectImage.php'</script>";
}else if($delete==0){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('This Image Used As Cover Image')</script>";
echo "<script >window.location.href = 'projectImage.php'</script>";
}else{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('mysql error')</script>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all it appears that you are escaping ximgid and coverflag with ' which would throw a syntax error in your sql if those were not varchar fields.

```
$del=mysql_query("Delete FROM project_image WHERE ximgid=".$_GET['ximgid']." And coverflag !=1;");
```

Second issue to address would be that you are taking a $_GET parameter and putting it directly into your SQL query which is just trouble looking to happen so I would suggest next changing it to:

```
$del=mysql_query("Delete FROM project_image WHERE ximgid=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ximgid'])." And coverflag !=1;");
```

if you need extra help debugging your SQL you can always temporarily put a call to

```
echo mysql_error();
```

after your call to mysql_query in order to show the error message from the server.

Comment: Please read question again, he said: `delete query work properly`

Comment: oops, that is my bad, I missed it primarily because the English used in the post was not exactly clear so I jumped straight into looking at a fault in the code.